# Conexão JDBC no servidor AZURE com criptografia SSL

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou com problema ao conectar via JDBC no banco SQLServer da AZURE usando criptografia.

Minha string de conexão é a seguinte:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://servidor.database.windows.net:1433;
Database=BASE_DE_DADOS;
User=Usuario@servidor;
password=senha;
Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=False;
hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;
```

Desse modo funciona, mas se eu alterar para `Encrypt=True;`

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: O driver não pôde
>   estabelecer uma conexão segura com o SQL Server usando a criptografia
>   SSL. Erro: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Falha ao validar
>   o nome do servidor em um certificado durante a inicialização do
>   protocolo SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)

Minha versão do Java é a `1.8.0_91`

E estou usando a `sqljdbc4.jar`

Grato a quem puder me auxiliar na resolução dessa questão.

Answer (score 1):

> *Se a propriedade encrypt estiver definida como true, a propriedade trustServerCertificate estiver definida como false e o nome do
>   servidor na cadeia de conexão não coincidir com o nome do servidor no
>   certificado SSL do SQL Server, o seguinte erro será emitido: o driver
>   não conseguiu estabelecer uma conexão segura com o SQL Server usando a
>   criptografia de protocolo SSL. Erro:
>   "java.security.cert.CertificateException: falha ao validar o nome do
>   servidor em um certificado durante a inicialização do protocolo SSL."*

Acredito que esse Link aqui vai matar o seu problema.
Bem no final da página, tem algo relacionado ao seu erro.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb879949(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Esse link diz que o nome do servidor na cadeia de conexão não coincide com o nome do servidor no certificado SSL. Porém um outro programa aqui na empresa escrito em C# se conecta aquele mesmo servidor da Azure com aquela string de conexão enquanto o outro escrito em Java tem esse problema. Já estou achando que essa mensagem esta errada e que o problema, de fato, é outro.